# If language x then:xyz, if else then:abc

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to do function in prestashop that will show one string if it's english and another string if it's other language.

I've tried something like that but it didn't work.

```
{if $lang_iso == en } 

    english text 
{else}

    Other language
{/if}
```

That's where I want to put my code. I wanted to code be in 'Proceed to checkout' place

```
<a href="{$cart_url}" class="btn btn-primary">{l s='Proceed to checkout' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}</a>
```

Obviously there is no option to translate it in prestashop backoffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use {if $lang_iso == 'en' }
```

en is a string.

Secondly, there is an option in back office.

Login to admin -> International->Translation.

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
{$this->context->language->id}
```

Regards